# Redirect to thanks page after function success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have next function (contact form, php):

```
function wp_ajax_contact_cb() {
global $_GET;
// security and parsing


if (! key_exists ( 'name', $_GET )){
    echo 'fail';
    die (); // bad request
}
$name = wp_kses_data ($_GET ['name']);
if (strlen($name)==0) {
    echo 'fail';
    die (); // bad request
}

$phone = wp_kses_data ($_GET ['phone']);
if (strlen($phone)==0) {
    echo 'fail';
    die (); // bad request
}


$mail = wp_kses_data ($_GET ['mail']);



//$email=get_option('atdgen_contactemail');
$email='aaaa@aaaa.com';

add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
$contentfp= '<br/>Name:<br/>'.$name.
            ' <br/>Email: <br/>'.$mail.
            ' <br/>  Telephone number: <br/>'.$phone;

$contentfp=apply_filters('comment_moderation_text',$contentfp );
echo apply_filters('comment_moderation_headers', '');
@wp_mail($email,'new messeage-'.$name, $contentfp, apply_filters('comment_moderation_headers', ''));


echo 'success';

    header("Location: /thank_you/"); /* Redirect browser */

die();


     }
```

**HTML Code**

```
        <div class="form_holder">
            <div class="cont_row flr">
                <input class="fll field1" id="fname"  />
                                        <label class="fll lb_inp nrkm" for="fname">שם*</label>

            </div>
            <div class="cont_row flr">
                <input class="fll field1" id="phone"  />
                                        <label class="fll lb_inp nrkm" for="phone">טלפון*</label>

            </div>
            <div class="cont_row flr">
                <input class="fll field1" id="mail"  />
                                        <label class="fll lb_inp nrkm" for="mail">דוא"ל</label>

            </div>  
            <div class="cont_row flr">
                <div class="fr all" id="cont_rep_msg"
                                        data-please_check_your_phone="טלפון יכול להיות רק מספרים, ולפחות 9 ספרות"                                               
                                        data-mandatory_not_full="כל השדות חובה"
                                        data-ajaxing="שולח... אנא המתן"
                                        data-success="ההודעה נשלחה אנו ניצור קשר בקרוב"
                                        data-fail="השליחה נכשלה, אנא נסה/י במועד מאוחד יותר , או צור/צרי קשר טלפונית"
                                        data-verifymail="אנא וודא/י את תקינות כתובת המייל"
                                        class="all"
                                        ></div>

            </div>  
            <div class="cont_row flr">

            <div id="sendmsg" class="sprite send fll" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'forms', 'send', 'contactpage']);"></div>
            <div class="note flr">
            * שדות חובה למילוי

            </div>

            </div>  
                        <div class="flc"></div>

        </div>
```

I tried to add `header("Location: /thank_you/"); /* Redirect browser */` to the code, but the form is give "error". only if i remove the header() function, it works good.

How can i redirect after the function sent? maybe on the html with jquery?
the form is not under "form" tag, its on div tag.

Comment: If the form gives you an error, your code might not reach the redirection because it aborts before due to the error in the form...

Comment: nop. if i remove the redirection code, the form work well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `header("Location: /thank_you/");`

Have you check the path exist or not ?

or redirect to none exist folder "thank_you".

You can try this if your folder "thank_you is not in the current page location

```
  header("Location: ../thank_you/");
```

Comment: i tried to google.com also :) not working. its not the problem. i didnt wrote the function and i cant get how to redirect from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

1. check whether thank_you is in the same directory or not.
2. if not in the same directory then give the location of the suitable directory. use `../` for parent directory.
3. I am not seeing the extension of your thank_you file. try giving that extension too.
4. Last and the most important thing. the blank spaces after the location creates a problem . It made me sick one day. So check for blank spaces and syntax carefully.
5. try using single quotes inside the header

Comment: Its wordpress (and yes, i know i can use contact form 7, but this its old site and code i did not wrote, i try to work on current code), so the page thank_you exist, i also tried to redirect to google.com - still not working.

Comment: stackoverflow removed the http:// and www before the link on the header code from last comment

Comment: trying using single quotes . let me know if it works or not by checking the tick :p

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try two things:

1) Run header("Location: /thank_you/") before the echo 'success' as when you output something and add a HTTP response header afterwards it could not work.

2) Check the redirect path to make sure it exists. (Example: create a separate php file and just run the header line with the path to see if it redirects to the path or it could be than the thank you page endpoint is thank_you.html or thank_you.php and the route /thank_you is not defined either in the app or web server rewrite rules)

Comment: Try ob_clean() before the redirect line just to make sure there is no output before the redirect. I would also check the white-space after "?>" in the files previously included. Try debug_print_backtrace() or debug_backtrace() or any other tool to see the full php stack flow and check for extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

First try to call the following line before header("/thank_you/");

```
ob_clean();
```

If its not working,

Try this:

```
http_redirect("/thank_you/");
```